# Display video stream from an IP camera in ASP.NET without using Flash

Tags: asp.net, video-streaming

I have been searching for the solution for ages, but got no luck.
The solution that I am looking for is to get a video stream from an IP camera.
And it's better that if I can get the video frames(images) instantly in the back end code, because the next stage of this project could involve some image processing.

As a part of requirements in my project, I don't want to use flash player to do it.
I am happy if you could find a way to make it.

I have tried the Microsoft Media Platform ([smf.codeplex.com](http://smf.codeplex.com/)) which I though it's a really good way to go, but unfortunately, this framework seems not perfect, it complains that

***“The tag 'SMFPlayer' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core;assembly=Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Core'."***

I did checked that after I typed "Core." the `SMFPlayer` will pop up automatically, but it still complains about cannot find it.

An I also tried the Silver Light, but it cannot get access to an IP camera.

Now, it seems to me that there is no way to do it.
I would be appreciate if anyone could throw me a light on this.

Thanks in advance.

PS: could anyone please provide me some live camera ip addresses? I have been searching them as well, but haven't found any one.

Comment: Have you seen this : **http://www.cctvcamerapros.com/Embedding-IP-Camera-Web-Page-s/326.htm**

Comment: @huMptyduMpty， Thank you for your info, I tried, not working. Maybe the ip address in the example doesn't work. Could you please find me a working one please?

Comment: Did you try using the exact IP on the article?? Have you changed the necessary IP addresses using you machine IP

Comment: @huMptyduMpty, yes I use the exact IP on the article, since I don't have a real IP camera.....

Comment: Obviously it will not work then !!!

Comment: If you don't have an actual IP camera to test with, it's going to be very difficult to prove that anything you're doing works. You want an IP camera of your own so you can control the configuration of it. If you simply can't afford one (understandable), many camera manufacturers have live demos, which you may be able to tap into. Check manufacturer sites for companies like Hunt, Axis, Arecont, 3xLOGIC, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out that I used wrong version of IIS Video smooth streaming dll.
And now I have decided to go with this solution.

Thank you all for your time and ideas :)

Comment: Please mention in detail how you resolved it. So that others will also come to know.

Comment: @Chandu-Indyaah Hi, what I did was to delete and remove all previously installed DLLs, and installed the correct version and double check whether the version on both sides match.

Answer (score 2):

I work at an alarm monitoring company, so I do this ALL DAY.

First option; most IP cameras allow you to request a still image from the camera by simply sending a properly-formed request to either the HTTP or RTSP port. The exact nature of that request differs from camera to camera and based on the configuration of the camera. You can use AJAX to make this request based on a timeout and place the resulting image on the page, and you can make the actual retrieval call server-side to get images and do your image processing before sending them on. Your FPS, however, will suffer if you go this route.

The next option is HTML5; the new `<video>` tag is supported by all major browsers (though only IE, Chrome and Safari support using it for MPEG). You can use this tag, pointed at a query-string request for the H.264 or MPEG stream of an IP camera. This will give you as many frames as are available (or as many as can be sent over the network pipe; that's a concern for most consumer Internet, not as much for LAN). Browsers that support this tag will have a built-in video player and will not require using a plug-in. The server is no longer involved in transmitting camera data; the server points the browser at the camera, which means that first the camera has to be publicly available if you expect to access it from any Internet-enabled device, and second, your server won't be receiving any camera streams unless it asks for them independently, so image processing is limited to what you can do in-browser (next to nothing).

Comment: I'm really happy to talk to a guy who is going this all days. After reading your suggestions, I decided to go the 2nd way. I actually have tried to use video tag in HTML 5, but got no luck either. So could you please provide me a fragment of code? Or a IP camera MPEG stream or H.264?

Comment: Unfortunately the cameras I know exist are secret or private; either nobody else should know they exist or you'd have to be on a VPN to get to them. And a "correct" snippet of HTML5 markup would have to include a URI to the camera (that's the key bit) which would at best be camera-specific; like I said, the query strings included in a request for a still or a stream differ depending on camera brand, model and features.

Comment: previously I knew there were a few of live camera for public access, so they are what I want, but I cannot find them. The brand of the IP camera I bought(on the way) is Wanscam, you can find it at http://www.lightinthebox.com/ip-camera-wifi-802-11-b-g-m-jpeg-free-ddns-bounded-supprot-16-preset-position-motion-detection-black-white_p209046.html   So what I want is a piece of code which demonstrates how to display the live video on ASP.NET website.